# Visual Studio Team Services Build Failed - Database Project to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-sql-database, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build in Team Services (was Visual Studio Online), with one MSBuild step that is configured to build and deploy a DB project, using a publish profile. I can't seem to succeed in authenticating it. When I queued the Team Services build definition, I am able to build the DB Project and produce the .dacpac. However, come publish time and this error comes:

**C:\a\1\s\Source\ShopDatabase\bin\Output\MyDatabase.publish.sql(0,0): Error Deploy72002: Unable to connect to master or target server 'mydb'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'mydb'.**

We're certain the user exists in the mydb and the master db in Azure.

Target: Azure SQL Database

DB project Target Platform: Microsoft Azure SQL Database

When I run the publish profile directly from Visual Studio, it works. But in Team Services build definition, it doesn't. I tried these as MSbuild arguments:

**/t:Build;Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="myproject.Dev.publish.xml" /p:Password="mypassword"**

and this:

**/t:Build;Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="myproject.Dev.publish.xml" /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=myproject.database.windows.net;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword;" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:Username="myuser" /p:Password="mypassword"**

and this:

**/t:Build;Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="myproject.Dev.publish.xml" /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=myproject.database.windows.net;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword;" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:TargetUserName="myuser" /p:TargetPassword="mypassword"**

But won't work. Please help me T_T been searching the net for 6 hours already

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a poor error message that likely disguises the real issue: you need to open up your firewall for deployment to Azure SQL DB. It's working from Visual Studio because you have your IP range enabled. The steps in [this guide to building & deploying from VSO](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/04/06/sqldb-cicd-intro/), specifically the post on [deploying from VSO here,](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/04/06/sqldb-cicd-part4-deploy/) should help. it specifically covers how to open up the firewall as part of deployment.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that explains why we can deploy in our machines (we explicitly added our public IP to the whitelist). We 're actually using MSBuild step and not Deploy SQL Azure step (so can't go the AutoDetect firewall) route.Would you know how to get the IP address of the VSO build hosted agent, then we can add that as whitelisted.

Comment: From doing some reading on this, the Hosted agent pool has no fixed IP address range, so you cannot whitelist the pool in the firewall.  My understanding is that you need to set the server to "Allow access to Azure services" in the Azure portal.

Comment: Changed plans :) We did the "Azure SQL DB Deployment" step and followed the firewall steps advised in the link of the answer above. Works like a charm! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JLDajoyag glad to hear it helped :) I'm not sure if there's a separate built-in "open firewall" step but it would be great to contact the VS Online team about this - there are a range of scenarios where that would be useful.

Comment: @JLDajoyag Yes your change in plan of using Azure SQL DB Deployment is a better route for security. That way, you can manage userID and password with variables and secure it rather than including them in clear text in your build profile. Regarding the firewall step, there is an option to bring your own build agent in VSO. Since you use your own agent machine and IPs are known, hence it is easy to configure firewall.

Answer (score 3):

An obvious answer (sometimes in hindsight!) but for future googlers the error `You must have a user with the same password in master or target server`

also happens if you are pointing your deploy to an instance that doesn't exist.
ie: Server was not found.

Answer (score 1):

Fwiw, was generating a script from visual studio. Running as admin made it stop being a douche about this. What a waste of my life just now...

Answer (score 0):

We recently had this issue and we resolved it by removing the @server-name from the end of the *Server Admin Login* value in the SQL DB Details section of the SQL Deploy VSTS Task. Some guides online say you need this but it appears something changed recently and it is no longer required.